# Basic Javascript: How can I link my HTML and Javascript on a Highcharts example?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm sorry for the basic question but I googled around and I couldn't get my simple task working.

I wanted to implement the Pie Chart Gradient example of Highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient), so I copy the javascript into a `piechart_gradient.js`:

```
$(function () {

        // Radialize the colors
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });

        // Build the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                    ['IE',       26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Chrome',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Safari',    8.5],
                    ['Opera',     6.2],
                    ['Others',   0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Then I place the given HTML lines into my web server's `index.php`, along with an extra line to include the local javascript:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="piechart_gradient.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**And I just get a blank page.** Shouldn't there be a single pie chart on `localhost`?

***EDIT:*** New HTML `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="piechart.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</html>
```

**Same results still**, getting a blank page on `localhost`

Comment: To help you with debugging, you can view source of the page, to verify  the html in your question is actually being submitted, and also fire up a javascript console to get more information on what, if anything, is going wrong.  ( every browser should come with both of these tools )

Comment: check if the js is downloaded or not, there can be an instance that the js is not download via your server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing references to `jquery`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-gradient/)

AH HAAAAA

i know what your are doing

you copied and past `jquery` reference after the `Highcharts` right?!
you need the `jquery` at the top

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Comment: Beat me by 16 seconds!

Comment: Same results, still getting a blank page. Please check my edited question above.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, bud. You stopped a headache that has lasted for at least 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a reference to jQuery. You should include that as well.

EDIT:
You need to include jQuery before highcharts.

Comment: Same results, with it included :(